# Convert mkv files to mp4 while preserving the name

Tags: macos, command-line, mp4, mkv

I have a folder with dozens of dmv files, but I want to convert them to mp4 via command line. I have successfully been able to do so using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i *.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy new_name.mp4
```

The thing I am trying to figure out now is how to preserve the name of the video. How can I do so without explicitly writing out the files name every time?

Comment: Your title says you have `wkv` files, your text says you have `dmv` files and your code says you have `mkv` files - which is it please? Are they all in one directory?

Comment: I'll edit that, I meant mkv. Yes all in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` combined with your original command to convert all mkv's:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -maxdepth 1 \
-exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${0/.mkv/.mp4}"' {} \;
```

This should convert any `mkv` file in the current directory to `mp4` while keeping the original.

If you prefer to remove the original `mkv` files and only have `mp4` remaining use:

```
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -maxdepth 1 \
-exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${0/.mkv/.mp4}"' {} \; \
-exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: It generated a `mp4` file but it does not accepted by `iMovie`

Comment: @alper: Why do want to convert them?

Comment: I want to import the file into `iMovie` in order to trim and crop; `iMovie` does not accept `mkv` or `avi` files.  When I do the following `ffmpeg -i *.mkv -ss 00:00:00 -t 01:22:03 -async 1 cut.mp4` I was able to import generated file into `iMovie` @l'L'l

Comment: @alper: But `iMovie` typically uses `.m4v` or `.mov`, so why the need to convert them? Maybe try `.mov` format, or just change the extension from `.m4v` to `.mp4`.

Comment: `iMovie` does not use `.mkv`, even I change the extension from `.mkv to `.mp4` it didn't help

Comment: @alper: Strange, that `iMovie` won’t accept `.m4v` or the result of the command above (Final Cut Pro does). Without a specific error message though I can’t tell you why unfortunately, maybe try `.mov`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU Parallel to achieve this when all videos are in same folder using:

```
parallel --bar 'ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy {.}.mp4' ::: *
```